# Python numpy saving arrays in different formats

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, export-to-csv

I am trying to save my data into csv file and I would like to specify different data types for different columns I am saving (e.g int for id, string for name), how can I do that?

For now with the following method I am able to save all 3 arrays as string.

```
d = np.column_stack((id, first_name, surname ))
np.savetxt('table.csv', d, delimiter=',', fmt="%s")
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. You're saving to txt, so everything is always going to be an ASCII string.

Comment: I need to load the csv into db2 as one of the database tables and I would like to store e.g. ID as an integer in this table

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `d`?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is simply different way to format the output strings, you can look at the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

> fmt : str or sequence of strs, optional
>
> A single format (%10.5f), a sequence of formats, or a multi-format string, e.g. ‘Iteration %d – %10.5f’, in which case delimiter is
>   ignored.

Just pass `fmt` as a list of formats, e.g. `fmt=("%d", "%s", "%s")`.

Comment: Since I need to load the data into fake database we're creating, I need to use the column_stack in order to get the desired format. Do you know how could I specify the data format in this case?

Comment: The stacked array is probably a string dtype.  `%s` is the only thing that will work.  With a structured array he could a mix of `fmt`.